# Wifi Connected but no internet after installing squid proxy

Tags: internet, proxy, squid

I am having issues connecting to the internet after I tried to set up a proxy. I eventually deleted it as I couldn't configure my settings to have internet. But I still don't. I rebooted my network manager, tried to open a web page via another browser, do updates - unsuccessfully. In Software & Updates->Additional Drivers there were none (And as far as I know there should be).

ifconfig:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:b9:6f:0c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:97357 (97.3 KB)  TX bytes:97357 (97.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:ad:d9:40:9f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::36e6:adff:fed9:409f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6052 (6.0 KB)  TX bytes:650 (650.0 B)
```

sudo lshw --c network :

```
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.16
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.16)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          do not display status
    -sanitize       sanitise output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
```

I thank you in advance and please let me know if I can prove you with additional information!